# open subset in constructible set of divisors

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, schemes, divisors

Let a smooth projective curve $X$ over $\mathbb{C}$.
Let a pair $(x, D)$ a pair xith a closed point $x$ and $D$ an effective divisor on $X$, such that $d_{x}:=m_{x}(D)\neq 0$.
Let $N=\deg (D)$ and  $X^{(N)}$ the scheme of effective divisors of degeree $N$.

We consider a integer $d'< d_{x}$ and consider the constructible set :

$\{D'\in X^{(N)}\vert ~ d'\leq m_{x}(D')\leq d_{x}\}$

Does it contains a subscheme $U$ open dense in $X^{(N)}$?

Comment: I'm confused, $x$ is fixed?  I don't a dense open subset of divisors will vanish to degree at least $d'$ at $x$.

Comment: That should have read "... I don't *believe* a dense open subset..."